# No package Thread, but tcl_platform(threaded) is true

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I've got Tcl8.5 installed (debian package).

I need the Thread library. When I do a `package require Thread`, it fails to find the package. However, `tcl_platform(threaded)` is set to true.

Why is this the case? Do I need to grab another package? I have tcllib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *package require Thread* isn't finding the Thread package then it either isn't installed or it is in the wrong place.  I think that tcl_platform(threaded) being true just implies that tclsh has been built with threading support and will support the Threads package.

Have a look in the TCL lib directyory for a subdirectory called something like threadx.x.x. If you don't have one then you do need to download the Threads package.

Comment: +1: That sounds like the problem to me too, and your explanation of `tcl_platform(threaded)` is correct; it just indicates that the C API supports threading. (FWIW, we're thinking about bundling Thread with Tcl for 8.6, but there are some tricky side issues there.)